# For each column, count number of rows until condition is met

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vectorization

I would like to create a vector whose values are derived from counting the number of rows (for each column), starting at the last row, and counting "up" until a `one` is reached. For example,

```
1 1 1
1 1 0
1 0 0
```

would result in the following answer `0 1 2`. There are 0 rows until `1` is reached in column one, and 1 row until a `1` is reached for column 2, etc.

I would like to implement the solution described above into the following code (`#TimeSince`):

```
Lattice <- rep(NA_integer_, 6) # 
Results <- rep(0, 6) # 
TimeSince <- rep(0,6) # 
Prob <- c(0.92, 0.90, 0.85, 0.80, 0.35, 0.15)

resultList <- list()

for (j in 1:100) {
  for (i in 1:6){
    if (runif(1,min=0, max=1) < Prob[i]){
      Lattice[i] <- 1}
    else{Lattice[i:6] <- 0}
    if (Lattice[i] == 0) break()}

  resultList[[j]] <- Lattice
  Results <- Lattice + Results
  #TimeSince[[j]] <-  count rows until '1' in Results per column

  }
```

Comment: something like `apply(m,1,function(x) which(rev(x)==1)[1])`

Comment: Are you trying to find the longest sequence of 1s for rows where zero is reached (+ those that have only 1s)?

Comment: @BenBolker if slightly modify your code to `apply(m,2,function(x) which(rev(x)==1)[1])) - 1` and rbind my list within the loop this works.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I am trying to find the number or rows from the end of to the first `1`, not the longest sequence

Comment: oops, yes.  By the way, if you come up with a solution to your question it's considered better form to leave the question the way it is and post an answer (you may have to wait a few hours) rather than modifying the question.  It's a little confusing for future readers to see a question that answers itself ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the tip about questions and answers, I'll post an answer later.  Also, could you point me a reference for the `[1]` part of your code?

Comment: Your code does not create an object looking like the grid of 0s and 1s at the top. Are you planning to find this data in a `matrix`, for example?

Comment: `which(rev(x)==1)` returns *all* of the indices `i` for which `x[i]` is 1,  in reverse order; the `[1]` selects the first element of the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code produces the result I was seeking above:

```
#Edited code based on Ben Bolker comment
for (j in 1:100) {
  for (i in 1:6){
    if (runif(1,min=0, max=1) < Prob[i]){
      Lattice[i] <- 1}
    else{Lattice[i:6] <- 0}
    if (Lattice[i] == 0) break()}

  resultList[[j]] <- Lattice
  dm <- do.call("rbind",resultList) # added in edit
  TimeSince <- (apply(dm,2,function(x) which(rev(x)==1)[1])) - 1 # added in edit

  }
```